# C++: how to show the result in the console window

Tags: c++

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

int main()
{
    int sum = 0;

    cout << "Please input a series of integers and any number of spaces: ";

    int i;
    while( cin >> i )
    {
        sum += i;
        while( cin.peek() == ' ' ) // isolate spaces
        {
            cin.get();
        }

        if( cin.peek() == '\n') // when press "enter"
        {
            break; // get out of loop
        }
    }

    cout << "The result is: " << sum << endl;
    cin.get();
    return 0;

}
```

Above is my code. I try to use cin.get() to show the result in the console window, but it does not work. It reveals a window flash.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You *peek* to see if there is a newline in the input. If it is you leave it in the input buffer and break out of the loop, where your `cin.get()` call will read that newline.

---

If you only want to read a single line, then I suggest you use [`std::getline`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/getline) to read the line, put it into an [`std::istringstream`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_istringstream) and read the numbers from that stream.

Also note that when reading numbers using `>>`, leading white-space is read and discarded so you don't have to check for that.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. However, I am still confused that I cannot see the result from the console window.

Comment: @FortranFun To fix the code you show, without making any other changes, once you see the newline you have to *read* (and discard) it. That will force the user to enter another newline for the last `cin.get()` call. In other words, you have to add a `cin.get()` call before the `break` statement.